# Linking Tables using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

Trying to figure out how to link two tables, specifically Medicine and Medication.

My script is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Physician.FirstName, Physician.LastName
FROM Physician, Consultation, Medication, Medicine
WHERE Physician.Specialty = 'Geriatrics'
AND Medicine.Name = 'Aspirine'
AND Consultation.PhysicianID = Physician.ID
AND Consultation.ConsultationID = Medication.ConsultationID
```

I presume that I would have to use INNER JOIN, but am not entirely sure as I am new to this. Query should populate physician name and specialty that prescribed Aspirine.

Comment: I agree you should be using an INNER JOIN instead of your comma delimited list of tables. For what you have so far, this would look like:  `FROM Physician INNER JOIN Consultation ON Consultation.PhysicianID = Physician.ID INNER JOIN Medication ON Consultation.ConsultationID = Medication.ConsultationID INNER JOIN `Medicine` ON <WHAT COLUMN DO WE JOIN ON HERE?> WHERE Physician.Specialty = 'Geriatrics'
AND Medicine.Name = 'Aspirine'` What isn't clear, and I noted here, is how `Medicine` is related to one of your other tables. What column does `Medicine` share in common with one of these tables?

Comment: Use Access query builder. Access is picky about parenthesizing multiple table joins. The GUI designer will put them in for you. Edit question to show sample data as text tables.

Comment: Google table normalization.  On the ribbon under Database Tools select relationships to hook up the tables.  Once that looks right google access query then use the access query designer to help write your sql.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a link between consultations of Aspirine and consultations of Geriatrics. At the same time, the way you wrote the query is very inneficient when tables become large, because you are doing a full-join of four tables. The Access query optimizer most likely fixes the inefficiency, but I still think it is not good practice to write code in this way. What I believe you want is the code below. It may look large and cumbersome to you, but I can tell you it reflects much better the logic of what you are trying to do and will be easier to maintain. I am guessing that the table "medicine" has a field called "medicineID" (or something similar), and the table "consultation" has an equivalent field. As I indicated above, I think that you are missing the link between these two fields. The code would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Physician.FirstName, Physician.LastName
   (-- Cons_Ger produces all the consultations by Geriats
    SELECT Geriats.ID, FirstName, LastName, ConsultationID
    FROM 
        (SELECT FirstName, LastName, ID
         FROM Physician
         WHERE Speciality = "Geriatrics"
        ) AS Geriats
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT PhysicianID, ConsultationID
         FROM Consultation
         WHERE True -- I guess you need some condition here. If not, suppress this line
        ) AS Consult 
    ON Geriats.ID = Consult.PhysicianID
   ) AS Cons_Ger
INNER JOIN
   (-- This produces all the consultations prescribing Aspirine 
    SELECT Geriats.ID, FirstName, LastName, ConsultationID
    FROM 
        (SELECT MedicineID, Name
         FROM Medicine
         WHERE Name = "Aspirine"
        ) AS Asp
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT MedicineID, ConsultationID
         FROM Consultation
         WHERE True -- I guess you need some condition here. If not, suppress this line
        ) AS Consult 
    ON Asp.MedicineID = Consult.MedicineID
   ) AS Cons_Asp
ON Cons_Ger.ConsultationID = Cons_Asp.ConsultationID
```

If this is not what you want, please clarify your question (list the fields of the tables "medicine" and "consultation") and I will try to provide additional support. More information at [LightningGuide.net](https://LightningGuide.net).